# Linearly independent functions not solutions of ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

If I have a set of $N$ linearly independent functions $f_1,\dots,f_N$, that may NOT be the solutions of a differential equation, and I impose initial conditions $f(0)=K_0,\dots,D^{N-1}f(0)=K_{N-1}$, is it true that we will always find coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_N$ such that the function
$$f(x)=a_1f_1(x)+\dots +a_Nf_N(x)$$ 
satisfies the initial conditions imposed? Or is only true if the linearly independent functions are solutions of a differential equation?

(Of course assuming this functions are differentiable up to order $N$)

My problem raises from thinking in $$\{sin(x),cos(x)\}$$
In this case is true the statement becasue both functions are never zero for the same value $x$.
On the other side $$\{x,x^2\}$$Are also linearly independent but at $x=0$ both functions are zero so the statement is false. I don't understand why the fact that they the first set is an independent set of solutions and the second not, makes a difference.

Comment: Presumably you meant to impose *general* initial conditions for $f(0),\ldots,f^{(N)}(0)$ since $a_i=0$ is always a valid solution otherwise.

Comment: Also, I assume you only meant to impose $N$ initial conditions, in which case you should stop at $f^{(N-1)}(0)$.

Comment: Sorry, Already fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear independence as functions doesn't tell you much about pointwise behaviour in general.

The set of functions $f_i(x)$ in this case are fairly irrelevant - all that matters is the set $f_i^{(k)}(0)$ which forms an $N\times N$ matrix $A_i\,^k$ if we assume we impose initial conditions $f(0)=b_0,\ldots,f^{(N-1)}(0)=b_{N-1}$. (Sorry about the weird mixture of 0-based and 1-based indices.)

Then the question is simply this:

> Does there exist a vector $\mathbf a$ such that $A \mathbf a = \mathbf b$?

or in general,

> Is $A$ invertible?

In general, regardless of whether the functions are linearly independent *as functions*, the rows of this matrix may or may not be independent. (For instance, the functions can all be piecewise defined as identically $0$ for $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and then become linearly independent just by having different forms in $[1,2]$, say.)

---

The reason why a basis of solutions to a differential equations are special is because - provided they are nice and nonsingular $N$th order equations, they give a prescription for evolving **any** initial condition $\mathbf b$ forwards in $x$. Therefore, you can *choose* the rows to be independent just by choosing each $f_i$ to have initial conditions such that e.g. $A$ is the identity matrix! ($f_i^{(k)}(0) = \delta_k^i$.) This is just what we mean by choosing a basis of equations.

Note that $x,x^2$ are a basis of solutions for a differential equation of the form
$$x^2f''+bxf'+cf$$
but that this is a singular equation, since you have to divide through by $x^2$.

Comment: @Sharkos I don't see why is the case of differential equations is not possible  $f_i^{(i)}=0$ ?
Thank you

Comment: If I understand you right, then you're thinking about this the wrong way: when you take a **basis** of solutions to a differential equation, it must be the case that from whatever point you choose ($x_0$) it is possible to construct any possible initial condition at that point. This is because a basis by definition spans the set of all possible solutions, and the DE has a solution with any initial conditions you set.

On the other hand, you can choose a **set** of solutions stupidly, like $\sin x,2\sin x$. These don't have the property you want!

Comment: @Sharkos Yes I understand. My problem is that I have a independent set of solutions of a fractional differential equation. I can't use the theorem that grants me that there is a solution to proof that the do satisfy the initial conditions.
So I have N solutions, they are independent...and I'm stuck there.

Comment: Well, I've never played with fractional differential equations, but if they're at least as singular as $x^n y^{(n)}$-type equations, you're likely out of luck, since these produce $x,x^2,\ldots,x^k, x\ln x$ type solutions.

Comment: @Sharkos They are not, they are analytic indeed. Some of them cancel at zero some not...it's a mess. Thanks you anyways.

Comment: Singular *as differential equations*, not having singular *solutions*. $x,x^2$ are pretty analytic, but don't span initial conditions at 0!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ be linearly independent functions and define $$D\colon f_i\mapsto \left(f_i(0),f^\prime_i(0),\ldots,f^{(n-1)}_i(0)\right).$$
For solving your initial value problem you need $Df_1,\ldots,Df_n$ to span $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is true in the case of differential equations, but not for general systems of linearly independent functions.

Since $D\colon\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ its actually fairly easy to find independent functions in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ such that their projection is no longer independent like for instance your example $x,x^2$. You just need some $g\in\mathrm{span}(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ such that $Dg=0$, which can be done even for $g\neq 0$.